I'm creating cigarette smoke using Quick Smoke. Is there a way to make the smoke appear more wispy?
I'm trying to create cigarette smoke using Quick Smoke but it looks too much like a cloud of smoke. Is there a way to make it appear more wispy?
*image is a Cycles render using Blender version 4.02.

